# How to implement UDP scheme in Rebol3

Tags: rebol, rebol3

As far as I understand source code, net device is already prepared fot UDP, but how to make UDP scheme?

Answer (score 0):

In this line of the source https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/core/c-port.c#L612, the comments say

```
In order to add a port scheme: 
In mezz-ports.r add a make-scheme. 
Add an Init_*_Scheme() here. 
Be sure host-devices.c has the device enabled.
```

I think the first instruction refers to mezz/sys-ports.r.  So, we have this example https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/mezz/sys-ports.r#L254, we could add something like

```
make-scheme [
  title: "UDP Networking"
  name: 'udp
  spec: system/standard/port-spec-net
  info: system/standard/net-info ; for C enums
  awake: func [event] [print ['UDP-event event/type] true]
]
```

You would then have to write an INIT_UDP_SCHEME like this one for TCP https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/core/p-net.c#L299 where TCP_Actor starts here https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/core/p-net.c#L92, and then initialize it here https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/core/c-port.c#L626

And as you say, the UDP does seem to be otherwise ready.

Comment: thanks Graham, net device must be switched to UDP first see reb-net.h socket_types, but main question is if the actor would be the same as for TCP or completely different

Comment: UDP is now implemented